# Convert a sql query having in operator to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I Have this SQL query:

```sql
select * from jobItem 
                        join taskItem on jobItem.JobItemId = taskItem.JobItemId
                        join taskWidgetCountItem on taskItem.TaskItemId = taskWidgetCountItem.TaskItemId
                        join EntityItem on EntityItem.EntityItemId = TaskItem.EntityItemId
                        left join costCenterItem on taskItem.EntityItemId = costCenterItem.EntityItemId 
                        left join facilityItem on taskItem.FacilityItemId = facilityItem.FacilityItemId 
                        where  
                              TaskWidgetCountItem.WidgetItemId in ( select WidgetItemId from BillingInformationItem)
```

I want to convert this query to linq

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: what you have tried so far ? What are the issues you are facing ?

Comment: I have joined the "BillingInformationItem" table with "taskWidgetCountItem" table on WidgetItemId but not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent to a SQL `IN` clause in LINQ is a [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8) statement.

```
IEnumerable<long> validWigetItemIds; // fill from Database or input parameters

var result = DbContext.JobItems
    .Where(ji => validWigetItemIds.Contains(ji.WidgetItemId)); // equivalent to IN clause
    // other LINQ statements as required by your usecase
```

Comment: Thanks @Georg, I have applied the same thing but the problem was in the next statement.